# Azure portal returns error 400 when trying to manage my database

Tags: azure

When I try to open the azure web-portal to manage my database with:
https://manage.windowsazure.com/@MyId#Workspaces/MobileServicesExtension/apps/MyApp/tables/MyTable/columns
I only get error "400, try again later or contact support". This was working fine for a long time and since a while its this error. I didn't change anything and the mobile app using this db is also still working, but I just would like to access my managment portal.
I'm on a free azure acount, so no access to proper support, but maybe here somebody can help?

Comment: Have you tried the new portal at `portal.azure.com`? Unless there's something exclusive to the legacy portal, there's no reason to use it anymore. Note: *Billing/subscription* support is free, so it might be worth you opening a ticket if you feel there's an issue with a service you're trying to access.

Comment: Yes, but the new portal is too complicated, can't find a view into my table. This was quiet easy in the old portal. I spent hours now in the new portal, but where is maintaining my tables/records??

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with MS-support:

"you should be able to find the Tables and record related to your mobile app under mobile section, if you browsed to your mobile app on portal.azure.com > Easy Tables, Easy APIs, Data connection, all of these blades are related to your mobile app,
to find your tables choose Easy tables."